# Flask SqlAlchemy how to call filter_by with **kwargs and column like expressions

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to dynamically filter a query to my database, i use the

```
List = mytable.query.filter_by(**kwargs).order_by(desc(inscrits.id)).all()
```

on of the columns is an address and I would like to filter on that address using the expression  Like %partof address%

so what I did was this

```
        if (request.form.get('Address')):
            kwargs['Address'] = 'Address.Lik(%'+request.form.get('Address')+'%)'
```

It didnt work as expected, how can i do that if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need query [filter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method. It receives list of SQLAlchemy conditional expressions. Your example will look like this:

```
args = []
if (request.form.get('Address')):
    args.append(mytable.address.like('%%%s%%' % request.form.get('Address')))
# Here will be another possible arguments
items = mytable.query.filter(*args).order_by(desc(inscrits.id)).all()
```

Comment: `'%{}%'.format(request.form.get('Address'))` would imo be a bit clearer, though just the same.